# Search & replace a substring

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for a substring in a string and replace with another pattern.
The search string is in between curly braces.

**Example string**

```
line = $lang['MY_KEY'] = '{search-string} wird in Analyse berücksichtigt';
```

I tried this code:

```
re.sub('([a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\$\' ].*{).*(}[a-zA-Z\.,; ].*)','\1replace-string\2',line)
```

And also:

```
re.sub('(.*{).*(}.*)', '\1replace-string\2', line)
```

I am getting some junk characters along with the replace-string in the output.

**EDIT**

I have one more question.
There are multiple search strings in curly braces. I want to replace each substring with different patterns. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have backslashes prefix the patterns and replacements with an r :-

```
print re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z0-9\[\]\$\' ].*{).*(}[a-zA-Z\.,; ].*)',r'\1replace-string\2',line)

print re.sub(r'(.*{).*(}.*)', r'\1replace-string\2', line)
```

EDIT: replace every second occurrence using a replacement function

```
import re
def repl(matchobj):
    global counter
    counter = counter+1
    if counter == 2: 
        return '{replace-string}' 
    else: 
        return matchobj.group(0)

counter = 0
line = "$lang['MY_KEY'] = '{search-string} wird in Analyse {search-string} bercksichtigt'";
print re.sub(r'{.*?}',repl,line)
```

EDIT: Use a dictionary to store the replacements

```
import re
def repl(matchobj):
    global counter
    replacementFor = {'{search-string1}': '{replace-string1}',
                      '{search-string2}': '{replace-string2}',
                      '{search-string3}': '{replace-string3}'}

    counter = counter+1
    if counter == 2: 
        return replacementFor.get(matchobj.group(0), matchobj.group(0))
    else: 
        return matchobj.group(0)

counter = 0
line = "$lang['MY_KEY'] = '{search-string} wird in Analyse {search-string1} bercksichtigt'";
print re.sub(r'{.*?}',repl,line)

counter = 0
line = "$lang['MY_KEY'] = '{search-string} wird in Analyse {search-string3} bercksichtigt'";
print re.sub(r'{.*?}',repl,line)
```

Comment: How can I specify the occurrence which is to be replaced? I want to replace only the first occurrence.

Comment: Checked it. Count specifies how many occurrence to replace. If I want to replace second occurrence alone, how should I do it?

Comment: In that case you could consider using a repl function instead of a string with a global counter that is reset for every line. For every match other than second return the same string. For second return the replacement.

Comment: Also, the search-string is not the same. Each substring in curly braces can be different

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the junk characters, but out of interest what's wrong with `re.sub('{.*}', 'frob', line)`?

Comment: I am adopting this solution in my code as it is easy. However I would mark the other one as the answer since he posted first and it also worked.

Comment: If you adopted this solution in your code, you should accept it. Don't accept an answer because it was posted first. Accept the best answer, not the fastest answer. This will help others later when they have a similar problem and find this question looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work for you:

```
line = '{search-string} wird in {Analyse} berücksichtigt'

>>> print re.sub(r'(^.*?{)[^}]*(}.*)', r'\1replace-string\2', line)
{replace-string} wird in {Analyse} berücksichtigt
```